# Field between 2 electrodes experiment

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, electrochemistry

We were asked to conduct an experiment that is as follows:

> Connect 4.5V constant voltage across 2 electrodes of thin Cu wire, dipped in a tub of copper sulfate solution. A needle is connected to a voltmeter which measures the p.d. across the anode. By attaching a ruler to the bottom of tub, and looking at the voltmeter reading for distance of the needle with respect to the anode, I got a positive straight line graph which I interpreted to have a gradient equal to the field strength.

What I am confused about is the linear relationship between potential and distance. I thought that V is inversely proportional to d?

Also am I correct in assuming that the x-y plane of the field lines means that the electrodes can be reduced to point charges? In which case it becomes like this:
[image]

But then in the x-z plane the field lines look like parallel plate capacitor lines, so I'm not sure which one is which.

(I know my question sounds very confused - we weren't taught this topic very well, due to the teacher being away for most of it)